# Compose unique svg appending multiple svgObject from external files

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I try to compose a unique HTML file composed by the concat of multiple svg, loads from externals file. I've create a function that receive in input the content of SVG file and want to append it to an svg child node already load in the dom.

```
function LoadComponent(xmlContent) {
    //the node name to append svg
    var gridCell = "Zone00";
    //svgDoc is  
    var itemGrid = svgDoc.getElementById(gridCell)

    if (itemGrid != null)
    {
        var oParser = new DOMParser();
        var oDOM = oParser.parseFromString(xmlContent, "image/svg+xml");
        var root = oDOM.documentElement;

        alert(itemGrid);
        itemGrid.appendChild(root);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("item not found");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

My Idea is to create a Grid into the principal svg, and Load in the cells other svg from external files. After all I want to animate the controls using SVG animations.
The loading does not work properly.

Thanks

Comment: How do you get the `svgDoc` object? Are you sure that one is created without errors and exceptions? Did you see any error messages in a browser console?

Comment: svgDoc is correct and i can see the Grid loaded, The grid is the main SVG

Comment: svgObject = document.getElementById("svgObject");
    svgDoc = svgObject.getSVGDocument();